# Referencing the session controller from the user controller to check if a user is logged in

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show

undefined method `signed_in?' for #<UsersController:0x5bf3980>

Rails.root: C:/test_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:91:in `signed_in_user'

Request
Parameters:
{"id"=>"1"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:
None
```

In Users_Controller

```
    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please Sign In." unless signed_in?
    end
```

In SessionsController

```
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

---

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
   cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
   self.current_user = user
end

def sign_out
   cookies.delete(:remember_token)
   self.current_user = nil
end

 def current_user=(user)
       @current_user = user
 end

 def current_user
       @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
 end

 def signed_in?
       !current_user.nil?
 end

 def create
         user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                                                          params[:session][:password])

         if user.nil?
                 flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
                 @title = "Sign In"
                 render 'new'
         else
             sign_in user
             flash.now[:error] = "Welcome, #{user.name}"
             render 'AdCon'
         end
 end

 def destroy
         sign_out
         redirect_to root_path
 end        

       private

               def user_from_remember_token
                       User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
               end

               def remember_token
                       cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
               end  
end
```

****EDIT:**********************************************************************************

I'm using the tutorial on:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users @ Listing 9.12

Listing 9.12. Adding a signed_in_user before filter.

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    .
    .
    .
    private

        def signed_in_user
             redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
        end
end
```

When I included the helper in the SessionsController I received the message

undefined method `signed_in?' for #
Extracted source (around line #9):

```
<div>
 <% if controller.signed_in?  %> <----LINE 9
 <%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path, :method => :delete %>
 <% else %>
 <%= link_to "Sign IN" , signin_path %>
```

I included the Helper like this:
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include SessionsHelper

I couldn't get this to work, so I copied the helper methods into SessionsController and the error went away.and now I'm having an issue with 9.12 where signed_in? is an unknown method. and it makes sense because signed_in? is in SessionsController via a helper. can the UserController access that function. I'm new to rails and confused.

thanks for all the feedback

EDIT:**********************************

Here is the ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery
  include ActionView::Helpers::SessionsHelper

  private

  def current_user
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Comment: A bit light on details. Isn't there a helper? Are you using any framework?

Comment: `UsersController < SessionsController`? If the answer is no, it means that there's no way you can call the `signed_in?` method like that.

Comment: Dave, I'm working on authentication for test server.  I added the helper. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring your shared methods in the wrong place. `signed_in?` should be defined inside your `ApplicationController`, which is the shared base class for all your other controllers. There is, in essence, no way for you to do what you're trying to do. The `UsersController` can't access your `SessionController`'s methods, nor should it be able to. That isn't how controllers work.

`current_user`, `current_user=`, and `signed_in?` all belong in your `ApplicationController`, not your `SessionsController`, because they're shared methods meant to be used by *all* your controllers which inherit from `ApplicationController`.

Comment: The tutorial is incorrect. `current_user` is an *extremely* common method in Rails apps, and it is *always* defined in `ApplicationController.`

Comment: Included the ApplicationController in the Post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I had a sessionhelper file from another project open and I was editing that one instead of the one associated with my current project. Thanks for the help.